# PHP/regex - get certain number from a string

Tags: php, regex

Need quick help with regexp, to search a string for

```
blah blah blah price 4.000 blah blah
```

and assign 4.000 or whatever number comes after price to a variable.

Comment: preg_match("/price (.*?) /i", $string, $match);

Comment: As can be seen from the posts below, even after the regular expression match, it *behooves one* to *try* converting the extracted data into a number and react to any failures accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('~price\s+(\S+)~', $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: This will match `price :-(` :-)

Comment: @pst: are you sure? ;-) What about `$matches[1]`?

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uIitwm - $matches[1] is `:-(` I should have said "will accept `price :-(`".

Comment: @pst: yep. That's because I've solved the task of parsing the data, not its validation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = preg_replace('/price ([\d,\.]+)/', '\1', $string);
```

or

```
preg_match('/price ([\d,\.]+)/', $string, $matches);
$num = $matches[1];
```

Comment: It will not match `4.000` ;-)

Comment: It will not match `4.000` :-/

Comment: will this work if the number contains a decimal point (dot) and a thousand separator (comma)?

Comment: @pst - Yep. You don't want to commit the crime of [unnecessary escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331832/java-regex-engine-crashing/4331875#4331875) :)

Comment: @pst - Also, you changed your comment about escaping `.` while I was replying to it.

Comment: @Renesis Yeah, it seemed too pedantic and warranted removal. Your link it better :)